# Check if Javascript boolean is set?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to determine if a Javascript boolean is set?  Here's an example of what I've been doing.  It seems a bit excessive but I need to determine **if** a value is actually set, not just if it's true:

```
function doSomething (params, defaults) {

    params = params || {};
    defaults = defaults || {};

    var required = (params.required === true || params.required === false) 
        ? params.required
        : (defaults.required === true || defaults.required === false)
            ? defaults.required
            : true;

    if (required) {
        // perform logic
    }
}
```

Comment: [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) would be a good guess.

Comment: Are you in `use strict` mode or just plain old javascript? :)

Answer (score 2):

If a value hasn't been set that means it's [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

```js
function printStuff(params) {
  if (params.hello !== undefined) {
    console.log(params.hello);
  } else {
    console.log('Hello, ');
  }
}

printStuff({ });
printStuff({
  hello: 'World'
});
```

To further drive the point home, here's how it can be used with booleans.

```js
function schrodinger(params) {
  if (params.dead === undefined) {
    console.log('The cat is neither dead nor alive');
  } else if (params.dead) {
    console.log('The cat is dead');
  } else if (!params.dead) {
    console.log('The cat is alive');
  }
}

schrodinger({
  // Not specified
});

schrodinger({
  dead: true
});

schrodinger({
  dead: false
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check whether an object has a specific property, that's the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) keyword:

```
'required' in params
```

There's also the `hasOwnProperty` method, if you need to exclude properties inherited from a prototype (you probably don't for this case):

```
params.hasOwnProperty('required')
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this solve your problem?

```
if(required!=undefined)
```